# Eu gostaria de saber como inverter a posição de dois itens dentro de um Array

Tags: c#, winforms, matriz

public partial class Form_Bubble_Sort : Form
{
double[] nums = new double[200];
int clicks = 0;
public Form_Bubble_Sort()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void Btn_Voltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_Ini form = new Form_Ini();
        form.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void TB_Adicionar_Numeros_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Btn_Adicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
            double num = Convert.ToDouble(TB_Adicionar_Numeros.Text);
            nums[clicks] = num;
            LBox_Numeros_Adicionados.Items.Add(num);
            TB_Adicionar_Numeros.Clear();
            TB_Adicionar_Numeros.Focus();
    }

    public void Btn_Ordenar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < nums.Length * 10)
        {
            if (nums[i] < nums[i-1])
            {
                **//AQUI DENTRO EU IREI MUDAR A POSIÇÃO DO ITEM NA MATRIZ**
            }
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer inverter os valores de 2 posições do array, certo? Para isso vai precisar armazenar um dos valores temporariamente.

```
if (nums[i] < nums[i-1])
{
     var temp = nums[i];
     nums[i] = nums[i-1];
     nums[i-1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: vlws ai moço eu queria de alguma forma troca a posição dos items no listbox ai tive a ideia de deixa eles organizados em uma ordem no array e depois imprimir no listbox.

Comment: e vc me ajudo nisso :)

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado :)